# JavaScript check to see if a parameter is a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

Looking to see how you go about checking to see if a parameter that is passed into a function is a HTML element like `<div>` or `<p>`, etc... I've tried numerous things but nothing is working:

```
if (param !== HTMLElement) return undefined;
if (param !== Element) return undefined;
if (param !== Document) return undefined;
```

There has been some others but nothing seems to work - any pointers in the right direction would be great. thanks

Comment: have you tried making an array of html elements you want to check then comparing the results in something like an if statement?

Comment: `param !== HTMLElement` means: _“Is `param` not the `HTMLElement` constructor?”_. It doesn’t check if `param` is an _instance of_ that constructor. [`instanceof`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator.

```
if (param instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return undefined;
}
```